# Django: construct value of {% include %} tag dynamically?

Tags: django

I'd like to use an `{% include page.html %}` tag in my Django template, and construct the value of `page.html` dynamically.

Is there any way to do this in Django?

Here's a pseudocode example:

```
{% include page_{{mode}}.html %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the docs:

> The template name can either be a
>   variable or a hard-coded (quoted)
>   string, in either single or double
>   quotes.

So construct a variable in your view and pass it to your template via the context, say as 'modeTemplate': "page_"+mode+".html". Then do:

```
{% include modeTemplate %}
```

Assuming 'mode' is a python variable in your view code.

Answer (score 12):

I think that [goliney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065780/goliney) provided a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669962/110255)

In summary:

You can combine django's built-in ['with' template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with) to assign a dynamically constructed template name to a variable and the ['add' filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#add) and  to dynamically construct a template name.

For example:

```
 {% with template_name='page_'|add:mode|add:".html" %}
     {% include ""|add:template_name %}
 {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate plain strings and variables right in your templates using `with` tag and `add` filter,
see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524851/1444978).