# How to include templates dynamically in Django using "include" tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 10 html files with the names 1.html, 2.html ..etc 
What I want is according to a variable, a certain file should be included in the template.

e.g.

```
{% if foo.paid %}
    {% include "foo/customization/{{ foo.id }}.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible ? Cause the foo.id is not being translated before the includes tag works. As a result its giving a error. How can this issue be handled in a different way ?
Should I create a custom template tag for this ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do it with [add filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#add) and [with statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with) .

```
{% if foo.paid %}
    {% with template_name=foo.id|stringformat:"s"|add:".html" %}
        {% include "foo/customization/"|add:template_name %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

First you build a `template_name`, which consist of `foo.id` in string format concatenated with `.html`. Then you pass it to `include` tag, concatenated with path to template directory.