# How can I concatenate forloop.counter to a string in my django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, for-loop, string-concatenation

I am already trying to concatenate like this:

```
{% for choice in choice_dict %}
    {% if choice =='2' %}
        {% with "mod"|add:forloop.counter|add:".html" as template %}
            {% include template %}
        {% endwith %}                   
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but for some reason I am only getting "mod.html" and not the forloop.counter number.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on and what I can do to fix this issue?  Thanks alot!

Comment: should work according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates.

Comment: forloop.counter is an int not a string, which is what i think is causing the problem

Answer (score 51):

Your problem is that the forloop.counter is an integer and you are using the `add` template filter which will behave properly if you pass it all strings or all integers, but not a mix.

One way to work around this is:

```
{% for x in some_list %}
    {% with y=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
    {% with template="mod"|add:y|add:".html" %}
        <p>{{ template }}</p>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

which results in:

```
<p>mod1.html</p>
<p>mod2.html</p>
<p>mod3.html</p>
<p>mod4.html</p>
<p>mod5.html</p>
<p>mod6.html</p>
...
```

The second with tag is required because stringformat tag is implemented with an automatically prepended `%`. To get around this you can create a custom filter. I use something similar to this:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/393/

save the snipped as  some_app/templatetags/some_name.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def format(value, arg):
    """
    Alters default filter "stringformat" to not add the % at the front,
    so the variable can be placed anywhere in the string.
    """
    try:
        if value:
            return (unicode(arg)) % value
        else:
            return u''
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return u''
register.filter('format', format)
```

in template:

```
{% load some_name.py %}

{% for x in some_list %}
    {% with template=forloop.counter|format:"mod%s.html" %}
        <p>{{ template }}</p>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Ethan: this seems to answer your question doesn't it?

Comment: @dting - This works great, unless you call it with `forloop.counter0`, in which case the `if value` line will return "False" for "0".  To get around this, just change that line to `if value is not None`.

Comment: Worth noting that you need a __init__.py in the templatetags directory, and to restart the server, for this to register, as per: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to do this in your templates, this seems more like a views job: (use of if within a for loop).

```
chosen_templates=[]
for choice in choice_dict:
  if choice =='2':
    {% with "mod"|add:forloop.counter|add:".html" as template %}
    template_name = "mod%i.html" %index
    chosen_templates.append(template_name)
```

Then pass `chosen_templates` to your template where you will have only

```
{% for template in chosen_templates %}
  {% load template %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, I don't quite understand why you are using a dict to select the template with a number that is not in the dictionnary. `for key,value in dict.items()` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try *without* using the block "with"

```
{% for choice in choice_dict %}
    {% if choice =='2' %}
       {% include "mod"|add:forloop.counter|add:".html" %}                   
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: NIce, unfortunately this doesn't work with Django 1.9.