# How to iterate through numbers in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django. I just want to build an online resume based on the details given by the user.
I have separate HTML files for taking the user input and for displaying the resume.
I took the user input for the certification field like this:

```
<div class="box"><input type="text" name="certificate1" placeholder="Certificate-name"> <input type="text" name="institute1" placeholder="Institute-name"></div><br>
    <div class="box"><input type="text" name="certificate2" placeholder="Certicate-name">  <input type="text" name="institute2" placeholder="Institute-name"></div><br>
    <div class="box"><input type="text" name="certificate3" placeholder="Certicate-name">  <input type="text" name="institute3" placeholder="Institute-name"></div><br>
    <div class="box"><input type="text" name="certificate4" placeholder="Certicate-name">  <input type="text" name="institute4" placeholder="Institute-name"></div><br>
    <div class="box"><input type="text" name="certificate5" placeholder="Certificate-name">  <input type="text" name="institute5" placeholder="Institute-name"></div><br>
    <div class="box"><input type="text" name="certificate6" placeholder="Certicate-name">  <input type="text" name="institute6" placeholder="Institute-name"></div><br>
```

And the code which I have written in views.py file is this:

```
if(request.method=="POST"):
    dictionary = {str(i):request.POST[i].capitalize() for i in request.POST}
    return render(request,"form/resume.html",dictionary)
```

And the code which I have written for displaying certifications in the resume is this:

```
{% if certificate1 %}
    <li>{{certificate1}}, {{institute1}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if certificate2 %}
    <li>{{certificate2}}, {{institute2}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if certificate3 %}
    <li>{{certificate3}}, {{institute3}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if certificate4 %}
    <li>{{certificate4}}, {{institute4}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if certificate5 %}
    <li>{{certificate5}}, {{institute5}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if certificate6 %}
    <li>{{certificate6}}, {{institute6}}</li>
    {% endif %}
```

But I feel the code that I have written in displaying certifications in resume [2nd code] is not efficient. Is there any other way of writing the 2nd code? I want to know, how can we use **for loop** if possible. Or is there any other way? Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can group all your data in one array and pass them in your render function so you could iterate it in your Jinja template

Comment: I used many fields like skills, education, achievements, project details, and so on. And for each field, I have a maximum of 5 answers. So, I simply stored them in a dictionary by using a for loop in views.py file. Please check my edited question once.

Answer (score 0):

Send certificates as a list to template like this:

```
certificates = [
    { "certificate": certificate1, "institute": institute1},
    { "certificate": certificate2, "institute": institute2}
]
```

Then in template, display it like this:

```
{% for c in certificates %}
    <li>{{c.certificate}}, {{c.institute}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I used many fields like skills, education, achievements, project details, and so on. And for each field, I have a maximum of 5 answers. So, I simply stored them in a dictionary by using a for loop in views.py file. Please check my edited question once.

Comment: @VallamkondaNeelima even then you can just use a list for iteration and add the dictionary inside it as a list element like this: `dictionary = [{str(i):request.POST[i].capitalize()} for i in request.POST]`. This will allow using loop in template as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use arrays so you can easily iterate through it.
or if you just want to write in that way
use string concatenation for the variable name like:

```
{% for x in '123456' %}
    {% with y=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
    {% with names="certificate"|add:y %}
        {% if names %}
          <li> {{name}} </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

See this for more info:
[How can I concatenate forloop.counter to a string in my django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725794/how-can-i-concatenate-forloop-counter-to-a-string-in-my-django-template)

Comment: as I have seen that you have edited question... you are sending dict to template. So iterate through that using for loop.{% for key, values in certificates.items %}{{key}}{{value}}{% endfor %}

Comment: But now the **certificate1** is not a variable, it is a string-- "certificate1" and the above code you have written displays  certificate1 certificate2 certificate3 and so on but not the values of them which are provided in views.py