# Django Custom Include Template

Tags: python, django, templates, include

I know this isn't exactly Django templating philosophy, but i'd like to be able to include different templates depending on a list of plugins that I've specified in the http response context.  For example, if I have the following plugins configured:

```
 context['plugins'] = ['weather']
```

I attempt to include each template in the base template file:

```
{% for custom_plugin in custom_plugins %}
    {% include "map/plugins/custom/{{ plugin }}/includes.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've also tried:

```
{% for plugin in plugins %}
    @register.inclusion_tag("map/plugins/custom/{{ plugin }}/includes.html", takes_context=True)
{% endfor %}
```

For now the each plugin will only contain script references and css classes in their includes.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}map/js/plugins/custom/weather/weatherStation.js?ver={{ version }}"></script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using tag or variable syntax **inside** a tag is *never* correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first way seems the best, and this answer might provide some pointers as to how you'd go about it: [How to concatenate strings in django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates)

You basically want to build a string of the template to include in a variable with the with tag, then include it.

Comment: gracias!  easy solution, not sure how I overlooked this. Thanks Ben.