# Nested django template tags

Tags: python, django

I need implement something like this:

`{% include "pay_forms/{{ pay_gw.name }}.html" %}`, where `{{ pay_gw.name }}` is tag.
How I can realize this?

Comment: I try to include different templates from some context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"pay_forms/"|add:pay_gw.name|add:".html"
```

([how to concat strings in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates))