# How to concatenate a string to a number inside a template tag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I've found a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates), but the solution doesn't seem to work for me, unless I'm doing it wrong. I have a ID number, which I'd like to append to a string in a template tag. Here's my attempt:

```
{% with "image-"|add:vid.the_id as image_id %}
     {# custom template tag to generate image #}
    {% image vid.teaser_thumbnail alt=vid.title id=image_id %}
{% endwith %}
```

But `image_id` is coming out as empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

My desired output of `image_id` would be something like "image-8989723123".

Comment: `add` filter tries to add as integers, if that fails it attempts to concatenate them. In your case, a number & string will cause an exception. You could define your own filter like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23783666/781695

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this way (added `with` statement with [stringformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) on top of yours):

```
{% with vid.the_id|stringformat:"s" as vid_id %}
    {% with "image-"|add:vid_id as image_id %}
         {# custom template tag to generate image #}
         {% image vid.teaser_thumbnail alt=vid.title id=image_id %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Perhaps because `the_id` is a number?

Comment: @shrewdbeans please check the updated answer (added `stringformat`).

Comment: You can actually do it in just one step: `{% with image_id='image-'|add:vid.the_id|stringformat:"s" %}`. I've used `=` instead of `and` in the `with` since its the [recommended format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with)