# string concatenate in django template include

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to do like this in django templates?

```
{% for filename in filenames %}
    {% include filename+".html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you see I have a list of filenames and I want to include all of them using for loop.
And second question: if filename is an integer can I convert to string? Like this:

```
{% for filename in filenames %}
    {% include str(filename)+".html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What's the reason you can't do the string processing when you populate the `filenames` list in the view?

Comment: i'm using id s as filenames so they are integers e.g  1.html, 2.html ....

Comment: That didn't really answer the question. Why can't you convert them in the view?

Comment: what do you mean in converting them in the view

Comment: are you talking about render them like regular pages?

Comment: Ortographic corrections. Deleted superflouus things.

Comment: you can find your answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519109/how-to-concatenate-a-string-to-a-number-inside-a-template-tag-in-django and let me know if you still have any doubts.