# Django dynamic template variable inside if clause

Tags: django, templates, variables

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in "pseudo code":

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {% if 'can_access_page_{{page.name}}' in perms  %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{page.url}}" id="page_link_{{page.id}}" target="_blank">{{ page.name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How to do this? Permission names I can customize — but still can't figure out this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to slightly abuse Django's existing `add` template filter (intended for numbers but works for strings), as in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524851/202168

Comment: Thanks, I made it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom filter. Something like:

```
@register.filter
def check_page_perms(page, perms):
    return 'can_access_page_%s' % page.name in perms
```

and use it:

```
{% if page|check_page_perms:perms %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using add template filter.