# How to pass dictionary value as path to image in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am a beginner in django and currently struggling to pass dict value as path to image. I have dictionary in following format:-

```
{
                'features': [
                    {
                        'icon': 1,
                        'heading': 'Lorem Ipsum',
                        'description': 'Neque porro quisquam est qui ipsum quia dolor sit amet, adipiscing velit quia dolor sit
                        amet, adipisci velit'
                    },

                    {
                        'icon': 2,
                        'heading': 'Lorem Ipsum',
                        'description': 'Neque porro quisquam est qui ipsum quia dolor sit amet, adipiscing velit quia dolor sit
                        amet, adipisci velit'
                    }

                ]
}
```

Inside template, I am accessing images in following way:-

```
{% for feature in content.features %}
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mx-auto my-1 mt-5 text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                        <div class="h-40 w-100 d-flex">
                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="{% static "base/images/{{feature.icon}}" %}"
                                 alt="{{ feature.heading }}" width="100" height="100">
                        </div>
                        <div class="h-60 w-100 d-flex flex-column">
                            <h4 class="feature-caption">{{ feature.heading }}</h4>
                            <p class="feature-description p-2 pt-3 pb-3">{{ feature.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the images are not loading. Can someone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using jinja2 or djangos template synax? Because `{% static "base/images/{{feature.icon}}" %}` is not valid in django syntax (well, it is valid but you won't get the value of `feature.icon` in the string)

Comment: @Ralf why? It's perfectly valid, that's how you access a dictionary key in django templates.

Comment: @dirkgroten using `{{ }}` inside a template tag? That is new to me...

Comment: @vineet look at the final url in your browser source (using the dev tools).

Comment: @Ralf oops missed that. you're right of course. I thought you were talking about the dictionary access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using Djangos template syntax, I don't think you can use use `{{ }}` inside a template tag (that uses `{% %}`). So the following part is not valid:

```
src="{% static "base/images/{{feature.icon}}" %}"
```

You can try to use the [add template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add) instead.
This filter is not intended to be used for strings, only for numbers, but if both parts are strings then it works regardless. Like this:

```
{% with icon_as_str=feature.icon|stringformat:'d' %}

src="{% static 'base/images/'|add:icon_as_str %}"

{% endwith %}
```

Or just convert your `icon` to string in the view and forget about the `{% with ... %}` block.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524851/9225671

Comment: Otherwise just append the icon after static: `{% static 'base/images/' %}{{ feature.icon }}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that from your views you pass the dictionary as a variable named `content` , the way you are calling the values you want is correct:

```
{% for feature in content.features %}
    {{ feature.icon }}
    {{ feature.heading }}
    {{ feature.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Before that, make sure you have the `{% load staticfiles %}` declared as the very first line inside your html file.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Comment: inside `settings.py` what is the value for `STATIC_URL ` ? and also, check if `INSTALLED_APPS` has ` 'django.contrib.staticfiles',` value inside.

Comment: Also, Django uses some other templating language, very similar to Jinja2 used in Flask. But it isn't Jinja. Just beware of that, because there are some differences between those two.