# Django/python/static files/Jinja, How to concatenate string and jinja expression INSIDE jinja statement

Tags: html, django, jinja2

How to `concat` a string and a `jinja` expression inside jinja statement?

```
{% for pic in pictures %}
    {% if pic.name == line.name %}
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'orders/img/'pic.picture %}" >
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this tag with Jinja, the pic.picture is a jinja express but how to `concat` with 'orders/img/'?

Image:
[image: 1]

Thanks.

Comment: `{% static 'orders/img/' ~ pic.picture %}`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work ( everything right of ~ is ignored). Maybe it's impossible without a workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/) looks like Jinja but is not one - it has it's own filters and does not support all Jinja tags/filters.

Available options with Django [built-in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-template-tags-and-filters):

- **join strings with [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter** (although it is *not recommended* as will try to convert to integer, [more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates), but if part is clearly a string...):

```
src="{% static 'orders/img/'|add:pic.picture %}"
```

- no join, **resolve base** static **path** and **append** file name **after**:

```
src="{% static 'orders/img/' %}{{ pic.picture }}"
```

- more low-level control with [**get_static_prefix**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix)

```
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}
src="{{ STATIC_PREFIX }}orders/img/{{ pic.picture }}"
```

---

Jinja2 **can** be configured as django [template backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2).