# Django create path to an image file

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a normal app that has a directory structure similar to the following:

```
...static/
      Training/
            css/
            img/
            js/
...templates/
   ....
```

Within one of my templates, I would like to get the image name from the database and build the path to the image.   For example, if I had the image MyPicture.jpg, then I would like to include static and combine this with 'Training/img/' and the file name to get something like

```
'..path to static../Training/img/MyPicture.jpg'
```

I found the following article that suggested using template tags, so I have tried this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def addstr(arg1, arg2):
    # Apparently, add has side effects, so use this:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates
    return str(arg1) + str(arg2)
```

With the template:

```
{% with static|addstr:"Training/img/"|addstr:course.img as imgpath %}
<img class="card-img rounded-lg rounded-top" src="{{ imgpath }}" alt="Card image">
{% endwith %}
```

This is unfortunately leaving out the static part of the address.

How do I combine all three parts ?

[p.s.   I have a {% load static %} at the top of the template ]

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna show the absolute full url, this is what you need:

```
{{request.scheme}}://{{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}{{object.filefield.url}}
```

but if you just need to show the file, you can use this:

```
<img class="card-img rounded-lg rounded-top" src="{{ object.filefield.url }}" alt="Card image">
```

Comment: object.filefield.url just make the src blank.   The object that I am using is from the database, not the actual file.   My problem is generating a string that points to a certain directory.   I could do this outside of the template, but I don't understand why I cannot concatenate static, 'Training/img/' and a filename within the template.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake really.   All I needed to do was separate out the static and not treat it like a string.   This works:

```
"{% static 'Training/img/'|addstr:course.img %}"
```