# How I can concat strings in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm trying to localize a component with `get_current_language` and I need to pass the language_code inside a filter:

```html
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{{ field|set_data:'flatpickr:{"locale": LANGUAGE_CODE}' }}
```

but `set_data` argument is a string. How I can achieve this?

#### Edit 1

Tried with multiple filter chaining:

```py
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def fp_i18n(args, locale):
    config = ", ".join(args + [f'"locale:{locale}"'])
    return f'flatpickr:{ {config} }'


@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def fp_args(field, config):
    return config.replace(" ", "").split(",")
```

and then in HTML

```html
{{ field|set_data:''|fp_args:'"altInput":true, "altFormat": "d/m/Y", "allowInput":true'|fp_i18n:LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

`fp_i18n` returns

```py
'flatpickr:{\'"altInput":true, "altFormat":"d/m/Y", "allowInput":true, "locale:it"\'}'
```

Which is directly printed in HMTL

[image]

Comment: You could create your own template filter that gets the language code as argument and handles the rest for you.

Comment: Tried with ```{{ field|set_data:''|fp_args:'"altInput":true, "altFormat": "d/m/Y", "allowInput":true'|fp_i18n:LANGUAGE_CODE }}``` but don't works. `fp_i18n` takes results of `fp_args` and  `set_data` should take results of `fp_i18n`. I need to pass an empty string because `set_data`requires two args.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate strings in django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with a simple tag and passed the result as argument to `set_data`.

```py
@register.simple_tag()
def get_flatpickr_data(data, **kwargs):
    args = data.replace(" ", "").split(",")
    data_string = ", ".join(args + [f'"{k}":"{v}"' for k, v in kwargs.items()])
    return 'flatpickr:{' + data_string + '}'
```

Then in template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load form_tags %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_flatpickr_data '"altInput":true, "altFormat": "d/m/Y", "allowInput":true' locale=LANGUAGE_CODE as data %}
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Label -->
  {% if show_label %}
    <label class="form-label" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
      {{ field.label }}
    </label>
  {% endif %}
  <!-- Input -->
  {{ field|add_class:"form-control"|add_error_class:"is-invalid"|set_data:data }}
  <!-- Validation feedback -->
  {% if field.errors %}
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      {{ field.errors }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```