# Django slice variable in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to cut a slice a list of images to split them over a few pages of a pdf I am generating. But im not sure what the syntax I need to use is. (or if there is a better way).

```
 {% for page in image_pages %} // range loop for number of pages (passed from view)
    <p style="page-break-before: always"></p> // new page break for each page
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        {% for image in project_images|slice:"0:12" %}
             <div class="img-box" style="margin: 5px">
                <img
                  class="report-img"
                  src="{{ base_url }}{{ image.path.url }}"
                />
             </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

What i want to do is adjust this line

```
  {% for image in project_images|slice:"0:12" %}
```

To something like (to print 12 images from total image list sent)

```
  {% for image in project_images|slice:"page*12:page*12+12" %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own template tag to slice with variable arguments. The Django-supplied template engine doesn't include this. The authors believe that the right place to do this sort of thing is in the Python code. Something like

```
display = []
for page in image_pages:
    display.append([
        page, 
        project_images[page*12:page*12+12]
    ])
context['display'] = display
```

And the template then becomes

```
{% for page, image_list in display %}
    <p style="page-break-before: always"></p> // new page break for each page
    <div class="img-wrapper">
    {% for image in image_list %}
         <div class="img-box" style="margin: 5px">
            <img
              class="report-img"
              src="{{ base_url }}{{ image.path.url }}"
            />
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The other option is to use Jinja instead of the Django template engine.

Comment: I just worked out the working in the answer I posted. Your way of doing in the view makes more sense though. I will implement and report back. Thank you.

Comment: Works perfect and much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Along with this answer i did the below to achieve what i needed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23783666/14143473. I also used https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/

```
 {% for page in image_pages %}
       <p style="page-break-before: always"></p>
       {% with start=page|mul:12 end=page|mul:12|add:12 %}
       
            {% with start|addstr:":"|addstr:end as imageSlice %}
           
              <div class="img-wrapper">
                {% for image in project_images|slice:imageSlice %}
                <div class="img-box" style="margin: 5px">
                  <img
                    class="report-img"
                    src="{{ base_url }}{{ image.path.url }}"
                  />
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
          

            {% endwith %}
  
       {% endwith %} 
{% endfor %}
```